# How to replace `require_once` of native php in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to replace `require_once` of native php in Laravel ?

For example:

I want to use `htmlpurifier`:

https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier

**Installation**

```
$ composer require "ezyang/htmlpurifier":"dev-master"
```

**Usage**

```
<?php
    require_once '/path/to/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
?>
```

**Question**
I want to use it in Laravel, how to replace `require_once`?

Answer (score 1):

```
composer update
```

After that you can use `HTMLPurifier` without any `require_once`